# What is the probability distribution used by a python sklearn classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

When using the predict function of my sklearn classifier, I wanted to take a look at the probability distributions that it uses for its prediction, to estimate a confidence measure.

I am using the following simple classifier configuration:

```
clf = SGDClassifier(loss='log',penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=42).fit(X, Y)
```

And for prediction I am using:

```
    predicted = clf.predict(X_test)   
    proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[0]
```

But when looking at the probability distribution 'proba', I realized that the class with maximum probabliity value is not always the same as the class in the 'predicted' variable. Why is that? How can I get the same probablity distribution that is used in the predict function?

Comment: Can you reproduce a working example for it?

Answer (score 2):

From the [`SGDClassifier.predict_proba()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.predict_proba) documentation:

> Binary probability estimates for `loss=”modified_huber”` are given by `(clip(decision_function(X), -1, 1) + 1) / 2`. For other loss functions it is necessary to perform proper probability calibration by wrapping the classifier with `sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV` instead.

In your example code, you're using `loss="log"`, but not wrapping your classifier as instructed, which may be why you're seeing a discrepancy between `predict()` and `predict_proba()`.